# Assume $A \oplus B \cong A \oplus C$. Is $B \cong C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $E$ be a vector space. Let $A,B,C$ be vector subspaces of $E$. Let $\oplus$ denotes the [direct sum](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Direct_sum#introduction) of vector spaces. Let $\cong$ denotes the [vector space isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/441772/368425). If $B \cong C$ then $A \oplus B \cong A \oplus C$. This property has been used in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704204/about-the-injectivity-and-surjectivity-of-the-map-t-lambda-i-k-mathfr) thread. I would like to ask if the reverse holds, i.e.,

> If $A \oplus B \cong A \oplus C$ then $B \cong C$.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178841/cancellation-law-for-direct-sums). It is false. This question has also been asked for abelian groups and modules.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The link you attached addresses the case $B=C$. Could you send me a link that concerns the case $B \cong C$?

Comment: The first [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069257/does-a-vector-space-equaling-the-direct-sum-of-w-and-x-as-well-as-w-and-y-imply?noredirect=1&lq=1) also  answers this for isomorphisms as well. Read the last part of the answer by user14972:" e.g. if $V$ is infinite dimensional, then
$$ V \cong V \oplus V \qquad \text{and} \qquad V \cong V \oplus 0 $$ but $V\not\cong 0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Maybe you are using another "direct sum". Mine is the same as the one in the linked Wikipedia page, i.e., *"the direct sum of two abelian groups $A$ and $B$ is another abelian group $A \oplus B$ consisting of the ordered pairs $(a, b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. To add ordered pairs, we define the sum $(a, b)+(c, d)$ to be $(a+c, b+d)$; in other words addition is defined coordinate-wise."*

Comment: @DietrichBurde It seems from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968108/question-about-direct-sums-and-dimension) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580288/dimension-of-direct-sum-of-vector-spaces) that if $\dim E < \infty$ then $\dim B = \dim C$ and thus $B \cong C$.

Comment: Yes, this is the same as for abelian groups. So for finite-dimensional vector spaces the direct sum is "cancellable", but in general not (and this is what you have asked). See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27744/does-g-oplus-g-cong-h-oplus-h-imply-g-cong-h-in-general?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde You are right! Thank you so much!